# ionic exit iframe fullscreen mode to the wrong page

Tags: angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, fullscreen, vimeo

I wan't to play Vimeo videos in my ionic app.
I have a page to display the video.
i have an iframe inside the view that contains the player for the video.
when I click on the iframe it open the video on fullscreen mode.
when I exit the video it should send me back to the view that contains the iframe but instead it send me to another view which is totaly not related to that view. it's hierarchicaly a far parent of that view.
here's the code.

```
<ion-pane ng-controller="HowToVideoDetailCtrl as howToVideoDetail">
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
    <button ng-click="howToVideoDetail.back()" class="button button-white button-clear"><i
        class="icon ion-ios-arrow-left"></i> Back
    </button>
    <h1 class="title">{{ video.title }}</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content class="has-tabs background-stable" scroll="false">

    <ion-scroll>
        <div ng-init="howToVideoDetail.initVideo()">
        </div>
        <iframe ng-src="{{src}}" width="100%" height="360" frameborder="0" title="" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
        <p>{{ video.description }}</p>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

and the controller

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
    .controller('HowToVideoDetailCtrl', HowToVideoDetailCtrl);

HowToVideoDetailCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$sce', '$ionicHistory'];

/**
 * HowToVideoDetail screen template CONTROLLER
 * @param {object} $scope
 * @param {object} $stateParams
 * @param {object} $sce
 * @constructor
 */
function HowToVideoDetailCtrl($scope, $stateParams, $sce, $ionicHistory) {

    var howToVideoDetail = this;
    $scope.video = $stateParams.video;
    $scope.src = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + $stateParams.video.uri.substring(8));

    howToVideoDetail.back = back;

    function back() {
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
    }
}
```

}());

Comment: Android or iOS?

Comment: I use chrome and android emulator for testing and I have this behavior on both.